# Creating subsets of df using pandas groupby and getting a value based on a function

Tags: python, pandas

I have df similar to below. I need to select rows where `df['Year 2']` is equal or closest to `df['Year']` in subsets grouped by `df['ID']` so in this example rows 1,2 and 5.

```
df
    Year     ID   A   Year 2      C
0    2020    12   0    2019       0
1    2020    12   0    2020       0 <-
2    2017    10   1    2017       0 <-
3    2017    10   0    2018       0
4    2019    6    0    2017       0
5    2019    6    1    2018       0 <-
```

I am trying to achieve that with the following piece of code using group by and passing a function to get the proper row with the closest value for both columns.

```
df1 = df.groupby(['ID']).apply(min(df['Year 2'], key=lambda x:abs(x-df['Year'].min())))
```

This particular line returns `'int' object is not callable`. Any ideas how to fix this line of code or a fresh approach to the problem is appreciated.

TYIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subtract both columns by [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html), convert to absolute and aggregate indices by minimum values by [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html):

```
idx = df['Year 2'].sub(df['Year']).abs().groupby(df['ID']).idxmin()
```

If need new column filled by boolean use [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
df['new'] = df.index.isin(idx)
print (df)
   Year  ID  A  Year 2  C    new
0  2020  12  0    2019  0  False
1  2020  12  0    2020  0   True
2  2017  10  1    2017  0   True
3  2017  10  0    2018  0  False
4  2019   6  0    2017  0  False
5  2019   6  1    2018  0   True
```

If need filter rows use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df1 = df.loc[idx]
print (df1)
   Year  ID  A  Year 2  C
5  2019   6  1    2018  0
2  2017  10  1    2017  0
1  2020  12  0    2020  0
```

One row solution:

```
df1 = df.loc[df['Year 2'].sub(df['Year']).abs().groupby(df['ID']).idxmin()]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could get the [`idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html) per group:

```
idx = (df['Year 2']-df['Year']).abs().groupby(df['ID']).idxmin()

# assignment for test
df.loc[idx, 'D'] = '<-'
```

for selection only:

```
df2 = df.loc[idx]
```

output:

```
   Year  ID  A  Year 2  C    D
0  2020  12  0    2019  0  NaN
1  2020  12  0    2020  0   <-
2  2017  10  1    2017  0   <-
3  2017  10  0    2018  0  NaN
4  2019   6  0    2017  0  NaN
5  2019   6  1    2018  0   <-
```

**Note** that there is a difference between:

```
df.loc[df.index.isin(idx)]
```

which gets all the min rows

and:

```
df.loc[idx]
```

which gets the first match